# Sharepoint 2013 wiki template with web parts

Tags: web-part, filter, wiki, template

We're on SP2013 site collection.  I'd like to create a template for the 200 different profiles we have.  Each profile consists of:
1. wiki for tables and unstructured data,
2. wiki columns (display on page and on views),
3. web-parts for lists and document libraries,
4. dynamically filter web-part results based on the wiki page name.

I'm able to create individual wiki pages and manually add web-parts and filters, but I'd like to create a template so any user can fill out the page without having to add web-parts and filters.

Is it possible to create such a template?  Thanks.